# Multiple <a> tags changing HTML code depending on which one is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code..

```
<!-- LANGUAGE -->
<div class="languages_box">
    <span class="red">Languages:</span>
    <a href="#" class="selected"><img src="../images/au.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="../images/gb.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="../images/de.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px" /></a>
</div>

<!-- CURRENCY -->
<div class="currency">
    <span class="red">Currency: </span>
    <a href="#" class="selected">AUD</a>
    <a href="#">GBP</a>
    <a href="#">EUR</a>
</div>
```

Which produces the following result..

[image: My expected output]

I'm trying to alter the code so that when a user clicks on another flag or value, it updates the webpage to change with one is selected. To do this, I would imagine every `<a>` tag would include a `<?php if(something) {echo (class=\"selected\"); } ?>` but I'm unsure what the `something` would be.

Is there a way to do this in PHP? Or is it only possible in Ajax / jQuery since the page content has already been loaded?

Comment: Can the page be reloaded? Does the full page content change when clicked? Is it multilingual site or just setting the currency?

Comment: What you are saying is when you click on any language or currency the content is loaded as per the choice but you are unable to highlight the newly selected language or currency..Correct?

Comment: @Saskiumar This content is output on every page of the website, so it's reloaded frequently.
No, just this content.
Just a setting that I'm experimenting with. It will not change the language of the site, but may change the currency.

Comment: @user3438533 Yes, I want to highlight the correctly selected box on the same page. The functionality part can come later.

Comment: You can't run PHP-code in the front end on a button click in the way you want. PHP is server side (before the web site reaches the users browser), after that, it's js you need to use. In jQuery, it's a small task, though to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus PHP is server side code so it cannot be run on client. Using ajax to send request to server then handle the response would be the way to do it. But then your question is too broad

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahh okay. That makes a lot of sense. Any starting points I should look for to deal with this?

Comment: @A.Wolff Ahh thank you. Javascript it is.

Comment: I would recommending starting by reading a JS and perhaps a jQuery tutorial. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['flag'];
?>
<!-- LANGUAGE -->
<div class="languages_box">
    <span class="red">Languages:</span>
    <a href="#" class="selected" id="1"><img src="../images/au.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px"/></a>
    <a href="#" id="2"><img src="../images/gb.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px" /></a>
    <a href="#" id="3"><img src="../images/de.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" height="12px" width="15px" /></a>
</div>

<!-- CURRENCY -->
<div class="currency">
    <span class="red">Currency: </span>
    <a href="#" <?php if ($_SESSION['flag'] == 1) { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?>>AUD</a>
    <a href="#" <?php if ($_SESSION['flag'] == 2) { ?> class="selected" <?php } ?> id="gbp">GBP</a>
    <a href="#" <?php if ($_SESSION['flag'] == 3) { ?> class="selected"  <?php } ?>>EUR</a>
</div>
<style>
    .selected{
        color:green;
        font-size:20px;
    }
</style>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.languages_box a').click(function ()
        {
            var flagid = ($(this).attr('id'));
            var jsonData = {"flagid": flagid};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: "testadmintest.php",
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    window.location.reload();
//                    $('.currency a').removeClass('selected');
//                        if($.trim(data)==1){
//                       $('#gbp').addClass('selected');
//                    }

                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

<---- php code ----->

```
<?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION['flag']);
if (isset($_POST['flagid'])) {
    $flagid = $_POST['flagid'];
    if ($flagid == 1) {
        $_SESSION['flag'] = 1;
    } else if ($flagid == 2) {
        $_SESSION['flag'] = 2;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['flag'] = 3;
    }
}

//echo"1";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can send a flag variable using get, then:

```
if(isset($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == your flag)   
{echo (class=\"selected\"); }
```

use a flag for each link, and change the onclick function of links to be form.submit()

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not bother about the changed content as of now. So, I am assuming it will be handled separately.

You have already got the css class to display a currency or language as selected.

So, your html will look like something following(I am writing it for currency only, language will use a similar approach):

```
<!-- CURRENCY -->
<div class="currency">
    <span class="red">Currency: </span>
    <a href="#" <?php echo ($_GET['currency']=="AUD" || empty($_GET['currency']))?'class="selected"':'';
      ?>>AUD</a>
    <a href="#" <?php echo ($_GET['currency']=="GBP")?'class="selected"':'';
      ?>>GBP</a>
    <a href="#" <?php echo ($_GET['currency']=="EUR")?'class="selected"':'';
      ?>>EUR</a>
</div>
```

I am assuming that you have a GET parameter for currency which you can access through PHP. Apart from this, it is also possible that you might access the currently selected language from session variable (like $_SESSION['language']) which is the case mostly. It all depends on the server side implementation(PHP).